# Run a method with constructors from a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

What am I trying to do is to run this method in a thread.

```
public static void CreateTable(string tableSegment, string ConString)
    {
        string strCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + tableSegment + " (CVR text,Navn text, Firma text, Nummer text, Addresse text, Postnr text, Bynavn text, Noter text, Email text, LastCallDato text, NextCallDato text, CallStatus text, MailSendt text, UniqueID text);";
        using (MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(strCreate, conDatabase))
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conDatabase.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

So it should look like this:

```
    Thread T = new Thread(MysqlBlocks.CreateTable(txtSegment.Text, ConString));
                    T.Start();
```

The problem seems to be that I cannot pass the constructors in there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with a constructor inside. Start it in a new thread.

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: public void func(){MysqlBlocks.CreateTable(txtSegment.Text, ConString) }; And then Thread T=new Thread(func);

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write old school code pre .Net 4.X ([Thread is Dead](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/thread-is-dead.html)).  I highly suggest using the newer way to spin up threads ([Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html)):

```
Task.Run(() => CreateTable(txtSegment.Text, ConString));
```